# How to check if multiple values exist in shared preferences at once in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I know how to check for a single key if exist in shared preferences like this line for example:

```
bool check = preferences.containsKey('weight');
```

But what if I want to check for multiple keys at once, something like this:

```
bool check = preferences.containsKey('weight','height',userName...ect);
```

Is is possible to somehow check for multiple values at once?

Comment: You can do something like  bool check = preferences.containsKey('weight') && preferences.containsKey('height') and you can add more keys similarly

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap Thanks for your answer. I was looking for something simpler cause I have bunch of keys that I want to check for, and I dont want to have like 10 lines just to check but if thats the only way then I have no choice but to do it ig :)

Comment: Hmm maybe try my answer and let me know how it goes

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap ok I will try it and let you know how it goes

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap It actually did work but still the point that I am gonna have to write like 9 lines with this approach

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you won't have to, you can just make a list of your keys and pass it to myFunc(yourList) . Doing this will give you a bool value to use

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap oh I think I missunderstood you and didnt actually saw your posted answer. I was trying what you said in the comment "bool check = preferences.containsKey('weight') && preferences.containsKey('height') and you can add more keys similarly"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247591/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-kashyap-and-taha-khamis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method in SharedPreferences to do that, but you can writen an extension method to make it look like there was:

```
extension SharedPreferencesExtensions on SharedPreferences {
  bool containsAllKeys(Iterable<String> keys) {
    return !keys.any((key) => !this.containsKey(key));
  }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
bool check = preferences.containsAllKeys(['weight','height',userName...ect]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did work perfectly for me and it gave me the exact behaviour I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say you have a bunch of keys . All you need to do is do this operation over a list and then reduce that into one boolean value

Try this function

```
// Your function takes a string and checks 
bool myFunc(List<String> keys){

return keys.map((key)=>preferences.containsKey(key)).reduce((prev,next) => prev && next);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write two helper functions:

```
/// Will return a map with etries like the folllowing:
///
/// {
///   'weight': true,
///   'height': false,
///   'username': true,
/// }
Map<String, bool> containsKeyMulti(List<String> keys) {
  var containsKeyMap = <String, bool>{};

  for (var key in keys) {
    containsKeyMap[key] = preferences.containsKey(key);
  }

  return containsKeyMap;
}

/// Will return a bool value whether all keys are present
bool doesContainAllKeys(List<String> keys) {
  var containsKeyMap = containsKeyMulti(keys);
  return containsKeyMap.values.every((value) => true);
}
```

Usage:

```
var interestedKeys = <String>['weight', 'height', 'userName'];
var containsKeysMap = containsKeyMulti(interestedKeys);
var containsAllKeys = doesContainAllKeys(interestedKeys);
```